# How often does a waveform record come from two or more patients?

Tags: mimic-iii

http://physionet.org/physiobank/database/mimic2wdb/ says:

> the raw data file [might] contain data from two (or more) patients.

Is there any estimation of how often a waveform record comes from two or more patients?